# Grabbing a list of MemberOf based off a list of users

Tags: active-directory, powershell-3.0

I'm currently running into a problem where I am failing to get a list of security groups based off a list of users. The trouble is mainly within grabbing their "MemberOf"; since that is an array within itself. Any suggestions would be helpful!

Code below:

```
$companycount = Get-ADUser -Properties * -Filter{(company -Like "companyname.")}

$users=@()
foreach($user in $companycount)
{
    if($user.Enabled)
    {
        $ScriptObject = New-Object PSOBJECT
        Add-Member -InputObject $ScriptObject -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Sam -Value ""
        Add-Member -InputObject $ScriptObject -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Description -Value ""
        Add-Member -InputObject $ScriptObject -MemberType NoteProperty -Name MemberOf -Value ""
        $ScriptObject.Sam = $user.SamAccountName
        $ScriptObject.Description =$user.Description
        $ScriptObject.MemberOf = $user.MemberOf
        $users+=$ScriptObject
    }
}
$users|export-csv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to treat it like an array, much like you're looping through `$companycount`.

Keep in mind that `MemberOf` is an array of the `distinguisedName` attributes of each group. But the name of the group is part of the `distinguisedName` (the `CN` portion), so you can just use `Substring()` to extract that.

You could use something like this:

```
$ScriptObject.MemberOf = ($u.MemberOf | ForEach { $_.Substring(3, $_.IndexOf(",") - 3) }) -Join ", "
```

That will give you a comma-delimited list of names of the groups.

Keep in mind that the name of the group (the `cn` attribute) can be different than the `displayName` (for distribution lists, it's the `displayName` that is shown in Outlook), which may or may not be relevant to you. Also, my code there will cause problems if any of your group names have commas in them.